# How to manipulated DOM using JavaScript in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I am new to automation anywhere.

I am looking for solutions in which I can execute JavaScript in webpage using Automation anywhere?

There are functionality called Run Script but this is not working on browser.

Can anyone suggest how to do so.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

By using run script command You can run only VB script on Automation Anywhere. If you want to run JavaScript then Go to web recorder command and select Execute JavaScript option and run Your JavaScript Function there.
Take a look at this https://support.automationanywhere.com/hc/en-us/articles/230200888-Web-Recorder-Command?flash_digest=7d74e0f63d094062f0e56b7d0be9e6402719bc4c